# Book with 2 or three short stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

I remember years ago when I was in the Army and deployed, I found a book with 2 or three short stories.  One of them was about an Asian country shooting down an American Satellite and a mission to space that needed to be secret.  A fighter jet then flies extremely low over the ground toward where the rocket or shuttle is and uses his afterburner (at night) flying vertical over the launch site and pretends it's the space launch.  With the overcast skies, no one can clearly see the launch, just the light and noise and assume its a space launch.  I really enjoyed that book but I lost it.

Any ideas?

Comment: About how many years ago? Korea, Vietnam, The Gulf? Do you have any recollection of what the other short stories were about? Was there any science fiction or fantasy in it?

Answer (score 3):

Really sounds like "Lash Up" by Larry Bond c2001, printed in "Combat", Stephen Coonts, editor, Forge/Tom Doherty 2001.  The satellites are being shot down by  magnetic gun.  Ray McConnell risks his job & security clearance to coordinates an effort outside acceptable bureaucratic channels to put Defender spacecraft in orbit, and save the day  using lasers and tungsten penetrator-rods dropped from space.